# Alternative meat imitation protein options that are GF and soy-free

Tags: nutrition, food, protein, meat-substitutes

Are there any affordable alternative meat imitation protein products that are both gluten-free and soy-free in the United States?

Comment: Are you asking about imitation meat products or just protein sources in general? In the latter case, the are some questions with [good answers about that](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/1093/1250) already. In the former case, it might be helpful to edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Thank you @Vaelus for the assist, I'll be sure to clarify. I appreciate the link for the other info, it's helpful as well.

Comment: Are you okay with egg and/or dairy products in your mock meats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are some soy and gluten free imitation meat products made by two brands that can be found in the US. Products that are vegan are italicized.

Beyond Meat: (supposedly very similar to actual meat)

- *Beyond Burger*
- *Beast Burger*
- *Beyond Sausage Products*
- *Beefy Crumble* (claims to be "The only gluten-free AND soy-free crumble on the market.")

Quorn:

- Chik'n Cutlets
- Turk'y Roast
- Chik'n Tenders
- Fajita Chicken Strips

The Quorn products seem to be priced comparably to their real meat analogues, while the Beyond Meat products seem to be priced slightly higher.

Also, Mushrooms, such as portobello mushrooms, can sometimes be substituted for meat, albeit less convincingly.